# How to save a batch of processed images to a specific folder

Tags: python, image, opencv, preprocessor

I am trying to process a raw dataset sufolder and save the output images to a destination folder.

So for example:

Raw dataset in video_0001 should be saved in destination directory with the same folder name as video_0001

I tried the following code but since the dataset contain over 200 folders

here's what I was able to come up with

```
directory = "C:\\Users\\dataset\\distdir"
save_directory1 = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\dataset\\distdir\\save_img\\Folder1"
save_directory2 = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\dataset\\distdir\\save_img\\Folder2"

height = 512
width = 512


for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
      for folder_name in dirs:
         cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(save_directory1, file), img)
         cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(save_directory2, file), img)  
      for file in files: 
         img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(root,file))
         print(img)
         img = cv2.resize(img, (height, width))
         img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
         img = cv2.normalize(img, None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
         print(img.shape)
```

But the output is that in folder 1 and folder 2 has the last image only and this solution is not feasible as I have over 200 folders.

Any thoughts would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine the two for loops. Otherwise, you'll overwrite the variables img and file again and again and will only save the last processed img.

Try:

```
directory = "C:\\Users\\dataset\\distdir"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
        img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(root, file))
        img = cv2.resize(img, (height, width))
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        img = cv2.normalize(img, None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
        folder = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
        end_of_path = os.path.join(folder, file)
        cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(directory, end_of_path), img)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your preprocess logic first.

1. Walk through the origin folder to get the folder name
2. Create a destination folder based on the origin folder
3. Loop all files inside that origin folder
4. Do the image preprocess steps
5. Save the image to that created destination folder

For example, this is the tree directory of your origin folder

```
-dataset
- -folder_0001
- - -image_01.jpeg
- - -image_02.jpeg
- -folder_0002
- - -image_01.jpeg
- - -image_02.jpeg
...
- -folder_0200
- - -image_01.jpeg
- - -image_02.jpeg
```

```
import os
import cv2

input_dir = 'dataset'
output_dir = 'output'

height = 512
width = 512

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(input_dir):
    for file in files:
        # Create output directory
        output_dir_path = os.path.join(output_dir, os.path.split(os.path.dirname(os.path.join(root, file)))[-1])
        if not os.path.exists(output_dir_path):
            os.makedirs(output_dir_path)

        # Do preprocessing image
        img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(root, file))
        img = cv2.resize(img, (height, width))
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        img = cv2.normalize(img, None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)

        # Save it to the output directory
        cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(output_dir_path, file), img)
```

With this solution you able to handle 200 subfolders

Comment: Thank you for your help !
It is working and moving the output to the same folder name. But when I check the processed image using the following commands
 #Testing the Image
        test_img = "C:\\Users\\dataset\\distdir\\save_img\\video_1\\00004.png"
        image_sample = cv2.imread(test_img)
        print(image_sample.shape)
        print(image_sample)

Comment: It is working and moving the output to the same folder name. But when I check the processed image using the following commands:

print(image_sample.shape)
 print(image_sample)
 The output is 

(512, 512, 3) ...... Even though I can see the image turned to grayscale image
[[[199 199 199]  it doesnot seem to be normalize and when I divide by 255.0, all the images turn black.   Any thoughts on what I did wrong? 
'code'
  [204 204 204]
  [205 205 205] @taipei

Comment: I am glad that it helps you, but your new issue is another thing about OpenCV preprocessing the image, I suggest you open a new discussion to solve your image preprocessing issue, I will be glad to see more detail and help you. If you're not willing to open a new issue, maybe you can check [this](https://www.pythonpool.com/cv2-normalize/), because I saw you set `None`  for the second parameter in `normalize` [method](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga87eef7ee3970f86906d69a92cbf064bd)

Comment: thank you for your help. Can you please elaborate on what have been done so far.How the iteration was performed. Thank you so much

Comment: thank you for your help. Can you please elaborate on what have been done so far.How the iteration was performed. Thank you so much @taipei